# CSS alignment issues on close reasons with pending votes

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, google-chrome, close-dialog

"Should" word in italics is shifted down in the vote-to-close popup when there is at least one pending close vote.

Just have a look at this:

> [image]

Now without close votes:

> [image]

So the issue occurs when there is a close vote on it. It doesn't look good.

Tested on Chrome 27.0.1453.116 m, Windows XP.
And it looks fine on Firefox 21.0 and Opera 12.02 (Windows XP)

Here is an example of a slightly different but obviously related problem in Windows 7 SP1 and Firefox 21.0:

[image]

This seems to have something to do with how line-height and/or margin attributes are being interpreted.

Can this be fixed?

Comment: @Mat - Exact duplicate. However I voted to close that question as this question has more information including reason behind it. And browses information. :)

Comment: **Voted to reopen** because both questions are closed as duplicate of each other.

Comment: There is also a missing period after "Stack Overflow question checklist" on the same line with the italic.

Comment: @Aaron - Looks like it is resolved. At least it is not happening in Chrome (28.0.1500.72 m), Windows XP. Does it look resolved from your side?

Comment: Alignment is correct here, but the period is still missing at the end.