# Misaligned bold text in close dialog when number of close votes shown

Tags: bug, design, close-dialog

In the list of off-topic close reasons, when one or more close votes are being shown next to one of the reasons, bold text on the same line is misaligned a few pixels below the non-bold text.

[image]

The text is correctly aligned when a number of close votes is not present.

And when the number of close votes is present on a line, its text is aligned below the text on the same line.

[image]

Note that in each case, the bold text, and the number of close votes (which is also bold) are misaligned with respect to the rest of the text in the line that the number of close votes appears on.

This appears in Chrome 28.0.1500.70.

(See also a related question where [text in italics and URLs are similarly misaligned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186217/189912).)

Comment: Voting to close as this doesn't really warrant a separate question. A comment or answer on the existing question stating that this also occurs for bolded text would have sufficed. Keep it in one place please.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't see that question until after I'd written this one.