# Crooked-looking Close Reason Dialog

Tags: bug, vote-to-close

Just noticed this while reviewing a few close votes:

This is without any close votes attached to the question.

[image]

This is **with** close votes attached to the question of this particular type.

[image]

This seems like a minor graphical bug, but it was enough to catch my eye (and now it's all I see).

Comment: Related / duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186217/css-alignment-issues-on-close-reasons-with-pending-votes and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187134/misaligned-bold-text-in-close-dialog-when-number-of-close-votes-shown