# Baseline/alignment of close vote dialog text options

Tags: bug, user-interface, design, close-dialog

I've found [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186217/css-alignment-issues-on-close-reasons-with-pending-votes) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187134/misaligned-bold-text-in-close-dialog-when-number-of-close-votes-shown) question about this issue, but one is a duplicate of the other and the other one is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). The problem however still exists for me. As I am asuming that no-one will look at those questions again, I decided to make a new question.

The bug is that the bold text in the reasons is misaligned if the vote counter is displayed behind the reason. This is visible on the second line on the left.

[image: Baseline of the text is incorrect]

The problem seems to be a mixed up vertical-align for some elements. The vertical-align of the entire text is set in `.close-as-off-topic-pane .action-name` to `vertical-align: top`. The bold text is set with pretty much every other element to `vertical-align: baseline`. I guess it prefers to match `b` over inheriting style from the parent element. This bug with the css is not visible until an element is appended with a height that is greater than the text on that line, such as the vote counter.

The problem can be fixed by making a css rule that sets the `vertical-align` of the child elements of `.action-name` to top. The style of `.close-as-off-topic-pane .action-name *` will have priority over the style for `b`.

```
.close-as-off-topic-pane .action-name * {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

This problem exists at least in Google Chrome 30.0.1599.101 m and Opera (Next) 18.0.1284.11.

Comment: This legitimately does need more free hand circles, I didn't notice at first

Comment: @RichardTingle Free hand circles huh? You'll get a free unicorn with it: http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/953/aiwe.png

Comment: An alternative (and, IMO, better) solution would be to [use `vertical-align: baseline` consistently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224185/links-sometimes-float-above-text-in-vote-to-close-dialog-on-firefox).