# Links sometimes float above text in vote-to-close dialog on Firefox

Tags: bug, design, close-dialog, custom-close-reasons

While going through the close vote queue, I noticed something weird:

[image: Screenshot]

For some reason, the "Super User" link text is positioned several pixels higher than the rest of the text.
Apparently, this only happens when the blue "1" marker showing existing close votes with this reason is present.

---

Looking at the link in Firefox developer tools, it seems that the culprit is the following CSS rule:

```
.close-as-off-topic-pane .action-name a {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Disabling this rule fixes the display in Firefox.

Alas, it seems that, in Chrome, the link is normally aligned with the surrounding text, but disabling the rule above causes it to fall down several pixels *below* the rest of the text.
Also disabling the following rule:

```
.close-as-off-topic-pane .action-name {
     vertical-align: top;
}
```

does make the alignment consistent in both browsers.  Unfortunately, it also causes the radio buttons on the left to fall down.  However, disabling both of the rules above *and* setting `vertical-align: top` on the *radio buttons* instead produces a consistent look in both Firefox and Chrome.  <sub><sup>(Alas, I can't test the effects of this on other browsers right now.)</sup></sub>

Thus, I would like to request that the `vertical-align: top` CSS properties in the close vote menu be moved from the action names and links to the radio buttons, or that the HTML / CSS in the menu be otherwise fixed to render consistently in all browsers.

Comment: Ps. [This earlier report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186217/css-alignment-issues-on-close-reasons-with-pending-votes) seems to be about the same or a closely related issue, but it's marked as resolved, even though this issue clearly persists. In fact, I suspect that the "fix" for that issue on Chrome may have been what caused this problem on Firefox.