# Misaligned SSCCE.org link

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, close-dialog

The Off Topic close dialog has a small alignment issue. The link to [SSCCE.org](http://www.sscce.org) is misaligned with the rest of the text on that line.

The problem only occurs when there is a vote count for that close reason.

[image: alignment problem]

Not exactly a major world problem, but I thought I'd point it out.

*Firefox 23.0.1, Windows 7*

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I've corrected my question - the alignment only occurs when there is a vote count for that closure reason. For a short period of time, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361725/how-do-i-get-user-information-during-java-swingworker-execution) is a useful testbed to try and reproduce.

Comment: I can indeed reproduce it when a counter is shown.

Comment: This looks very similar to [CSS alignment issues on close reasons with pending votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186217/164403) (even though the text there was misaligned downwards instead of upwards).