# A minor detail: "super user" misaligned in off-topic close vote window

Tags: bug, design

See this:

[image]

I believe this is similar to [the problem described here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194177/misaligned-sscce-org-link)

Comment: Er, *of course* it's the same issue? Why would it be different?